# Unable to connect with QuickBooks PHP DevKit

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a application set up and have changed my config file to contain the production token and keys from that application. When I run the oauth script, I get to the page where it says I am not connected, and has the button to connect. Upon clicking that button, I get a pop up window that is directed to https://appcenter.intuit.com/NotFound, and it says "Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for".

I have seen other answers to this question along the lines of:

- Check the URLs in your config file
- Check the URLs in your application configuration on Intuit's site
- Check the URLs in your Javascript

I'm afraid I need a little more explanation.

For example, I see this:

$quickbooks_oauth_url = 'http://quickbooks.v3.com:8888/quickbooks-php-master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php';

Am I supposed to change that to something else? If so, what?

For, "Check the URLs in your application configuration on Intuit's site," what am I checking for?

Forgive me if this is all documented somewhere, but I have spent a good amount of time searching without finding anything.

Thanks!